# Django editing in place

Tags: django, forms, edit

I would like to display a list of records from my database, then for each record, have two fields which the user can edit in place without needing to be directed to another page for editing.  How do I go about this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a template for your page which holds the HTML for the list, the edit fields and a submit button. You can use the existing admin templates for guidance. Define a view function which handles the post and updates the database.

Answer (score 5):

This [egg](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-inplaceedit/) could be a solution, I hope that still you need it. Although I think I'm late.

Comment: This is a really amazing app! Got it all working in a matter of minutes. Thanks for pointing it out Goin :)

Comment: Is there anything comparable to django-inplaceedit that doesn't require jQuery?